# File manager that doesn't freeze when working with SMB shares?

Tags: nautilus, samba, nemo

I work at a company that uses Samba for file sharing, which means that I rely on it a lot throughout the day. Unfortunately, the service provider of the VPN has not been able to cope with the traffic that has resulted from everyone working from home, and so the Samba shares are frequently slow or unavailable. Even more unfortunate, when this happens, it causes Nautilus and Nemo, the two file managers for Ubuntu that I have tried, to freeze.

It's not just the current tab that freezes while it's trying to load. It's also the other tabs, the menu to the left and even other windows of that file manager. After a while I'm given the option to force quit. However, I often cannot start the file manager again until my access to the Samba share is restored because it will try to open it at startup and immediately freeze.

It's a bit like using a web browser that freezes all of its tabs and all of its windows if a website is down, offers you to force quit, and then hangs on startup until the website is available again. However (warning: snark ahead), web browsers have a brilliant solution to this problem called threads. Is there a file manager for Ubuntu that similarly solves this issue?

Comment: maybe pcmanfm or something

Comment: Can confirm from experience, had the same issue, `pcmanfm` should work.

Comment: Freezing maube caused by GVFS. Have you tried Dolphin?

Comment: @N0rbert I can't seem to install Dolphin. When I click the link on the website, it opens Ubuntu software, which says "Failed to install: not supported". Is it supposed to be compatible with Ubuntu 20.04?